# Search MKV metadata

Tags: windows-7, search, mkv, metadata

For my DVD/BD collection of films and series I used the MP4 file format because it is easy to edit (title, year, actor etc.). Windows itself offers the possibility to edit MP4. It is possible to search for those entries, for example: I will see a fantasy film or one with Bruce Willis in it, so I search for "fantasy" or "Bruce Willis" in Windows Explorer, and Windows only shows movies with this actor or genre.

Is it possible that MKV files can be searchable, too? I've tested a tool named Icaros. The title from MKVs are now shown in Windows Explorer, but I can't search for the titles, it doesn't find any file.

Comment: I edited your question, but I was not sure if the query was "fantasy or Bruce Willis", or if it were actually two queries, "fantasy" or "Bruce Willis" (I assumed the latter). Please [edit] your question if that’s not correct.

Comment: (K)onsider using Kodi. It seems it has everything you need.